# How to remove "No results found" label from the list when DataGrid has empty component

Tags: react-admin

```
const TabbedDatagrid = (props: TabbedDatagridProps) => (
    <Datagrid empty={<Empty />}>
        <TextField source="id" />
        <TextField source="createDate" />
        </Datagrid>
);

const Empty = () => {
    const { basePath } = useListContext();
    return (
        <Box textAlign="center" m={1}>
            <Typography variant="h4" paragraph>
                No products available
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="body1">
                Create one or import from a file
            </Typography>
            <CreateButton basePath={basePath} />
            <Button>Import</Button>
        </Box>
    );
};    

const MyList = (props: ListProps) => (
    <List
        {...props}
        sort={{ field: 'createDate', order: 'DESC' }}
        perPage={10}
        filters={orderFilters}
        pagination={<PostPagination />}
    >
        <TabbedDatagrid />
    </List>
);
```

In the result both are displayed, '**No results found**" and **Empty** component
How to display only Empty component?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The <Pagination> component takes a `limit` prop.

[From the React-Admin docs](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#the-pagination-component)

> limit: An element that is displayed if there is no data to show (default: <PaginationLimit>)

You could try passing null `<PostPagination limit={null} />` to hide that default "No results found" message.

Comment: you right, but with empty string build doesn't fire, 'limit={null}' is the solution, because limit must to be a ReactElement, pls update your answer and I will accept it. Thx for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can replace these messages with your: [Translating The Empty Page](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Translation.html#translating-the-empty-page)

Comment: each list must to have different no results message, this label is displayed in <PaginationLimit>, maybe somehow we can to hide this, I tried with div inside of PostPagination, but with no success => const PostPagination = (props) => (
 <Pagination rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 50]} {...props}>
  <div style={{display: 'none' }}>
  <PaginationLimit></PaginationLimit>
  </div>
 </Pagination>
);